# Is There A Driver For Killer E3100G 2.5 gigabit Ethernet Controller In 20.02LTS?

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I used the ISO for Ubuntu 20.04 and it installed fine, but it does not connect to the internet. **Is there a driver for Killer E3100G 2.5 gigabit Ethernet Controller in Ubuntu 20.02LTS**?

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -`a command is:

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co. Ltd. Device [10ec:300] (rev 06) Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:3102] Kernel modules: r8169 05:00.0 Network controller 
[0280] Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)

Linux BlackKnight 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x 86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU?Linux
```

Comment: So what is the question? How it is related to the title?

Comment: Retitle your question to be your *actual question related to 20.04*.  Your question has nothing to do with the ISO.

Comment: Title Fixed Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -a` command.

Comment: Output added Thanks

Comment: just FYI:  But Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is the 2020-April release (ie. *year.month* format is used with 2000 added to the year).  Your 5.4 kernel in your paste highlights you used the original ISO or 20.04.1, as 20.04.2 used the 5.8 kernel, 20.04.3 used the 5.11 kernel, 20.04.4 used the 5.13 kernel & 20.04.5 uses the 5.15 kernel for Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS. ie. there are many 20.04 ISOs for download; you started with a very old one (great for older hardware.... but *drivers* are actually kernel modules thus kernel stack used matters).  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS uses the 5.15 kernel

Answer (score 1):

You installed from a wrong iso. The easiest way would be to install Ubuntu 22.04 or 20.04.4.

These releases have a kernel that supports this device.

An alternative way is to connect to the internet using e.g. wireless tethering and run:

```
 sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

then reboot.

Comment: Would you know where I can get a good copy of Ubuntu 22.04. The start of this was a bad copy of Ubuntu 22.04 which I downloaded from Ubuntu website. Thanks.

Comment: The iso at ubuntu.com is good.

Comment: Is there a way to download it using windows then copy to a usb instead of the terminal command you give? I perfer just getting a good iso of Ubuntu 22.04 as you suggest.

Comment: There are no "bad copies" at the official site.

Comment: Okay I will try again to down load and install Ubuntu 22.04 from ubuntu.com. The boot repair tool I ran after gave me "linux on nvme0n1p8 is 32 bit" which to me is weird. Any ideas on that? No insult to Ubuntu.com intended I am just saying what happened. :-)

Comment: It is unclear what you tell about 32-bit linux. You can ask a new question and describe it properly with real outputs.

Comment: I should have verified the Ubuntu 22.04 iso before I used it. Thanks.

Comment: I am not allowed to move to chat so I will no longer comment on the question.